# How do I process forms/data via Ajax for a Quiz-like game in CakePHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have written a game in PHP, but I am planning to rewrite it OOP and with CakePHP. Starting it was pretty easy and it seems I wasted a lot of productivity in having written all the queries myself etc. I spent almost 20 hours (wasted much though), while with Cake it could've been done in a few hours.

This leaves me more time for making the game smoother and better. I was using simple forms in the game in PHP, but I would like to do it better this time.

I see so much helpers in Cakephp and am not sure what to use. The game is for a my personal language learning site and is like Rosetta Stone. Users should click on 1 of the 4 images when they see a text like "perro (Spanish)".

What would be the best way to implement this? I was thinking about xmlHttprequest forms that use Javascript. Jquery, Ajax, or prototype.

I am however embarrassed to say that after having had multiple sites and have always heard people say Javascript is easy, never having programmed any Javascript and don't find it easy-looking at all compared to PHP. Can somebody point me in the right direction? It just seems that I shouldn't be using POST-forms here. What should I use to optimize user experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation for `JsHelper`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js)? It will probably answer some of your questions. Have a look at the `JsHelper::request()` method.

> Jquery, Ajax, or prototype.

`JsHelper` is a PHP abstraction layer that can plug into a few different Javascript libraries (including jQuery and Prototype). [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), however, isn't a javascript library ;)

You can inspect the output from the helper to see what the produced Javascript code looks like for each of these Javascript libraries.

Note: You don't have to use this helper to do Ajax with CakePHP, and can instead include pure Javascript files into your project. Doing this would help you learn Javascript and allow you to do more powerful things, but given that you are currently more familiar with PHP this approach should provide a lower barrier-to-entry.